# Install ASUS AC88 Without Internet

Tags: wireless, system-installation, asus

I am trying to install Ubuntu to learn it. So, I am new. I installed Ubuntu Server 17.04 on my desktop. But, it does not recognize my ASUS AC88 wifi adapter. I followed the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/30140 but, they did not work. Note that I can't access the internet to download packages. I saw some things online about using wireless-tools. But, I cannot download the package. Let me know any additional information you would like. Thanks.

Edit: I found instructions here: https://rhees.nl/2017/03/10/HOWTO-install-drivers-for-the-Asus-PCE-AC88-on-Debian-Jessie/ Again, it involves a lot of packages not currently installed. If someone could piece together a way to do it offline (with help from a laptop perhaps), I would appreciate it. Though a cleaner method is still preferred.

Edit2: I have also found this: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135321 Comment 17 on the thread claims they got it working (two days ago). I don't understand what they did. They summarize it as:

```
Yep it was the kernel driver.  Replaced the module brcmfmac with the module wl and 
the wifi device lit up.
```

Comment: Probably not supported yet: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_PCE-AC88

Comment: @MichaelBay Here seems to be something: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2337200 But, I cannot use binwalk since I cannot install it without internet.

Comment: What happens when you `sudo modprobe brcmfmac`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Nothing.

Comment: After a reboot does `lsmod` show brcmfmac in the results?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes, it shows that it has a size of 307200, and 0 uses. It also has cfg80211 and brcmutil listed as used by brcmfmac.

Comment: Then you should just have to `dmesg | grep brcm` and find the name of the firmware it is looking for.  Download it with another computer and transfer it to the Ubuntu machine and put it in /lib/firmware/brcm then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thank you for your help. It says that the direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin failed with error -2.  I assume I need to find brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin.  How do I do that?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I found it and installed it where you said. When I type sudo modprobe brcmfmac, still nothing happens.

Comment: Still have the error about the firmware not being found with the command I gave last?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Now it says "brcmfmac4366c-pcie.txt failed with error -2".  It then posts a lot of lines with failures of various kinds.  I can get you a better listing if you'd like.  It ends with "brcmf_pcie_attach_bus: dongle is not responding"